# Any software to transcribe Japanese audio?

Tags: discussion

I have some recordings of Japanese speech that I can't clearly hear and it's a bit annoying to have to unplug my earphones and set my speakers on full blast so to pick it back up on my mic and have it transcribed through my phone or something.

Is there any software that's free where I can just put an mp3 in (or even better, just play the audio on my computer) and it'll automatically transcribe it into text that I can copy and paste?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess one way is converting into mp4 and use [youtube studio](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6373554?hl=ja#zippy=%2C%E9%95%B7%E6%99%82%E9%96%93%E3%81%AE%E5%8B%95%E7%94%BB%E3%81%A8-youtube-%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E8%87%AA%E5%8B%95%E5%AD%97%E5%B9%95%E8%B5%B7%E3%81%93%E3%81%97%E6%A9%9F%E8%83%BD). Or [this software](https://vrew.voyagerx.com/ja/) comes top by searching e.g. 字幕 自動生成 mp3.

Answer (score 2):

There are few websites which have this feature; you upload the audio file and you get the transcription as text file.
I must mention that the websites are not fully accurate; occasional errors creep into the transcriptions. Some of them give you a chance to check the transcription though.
List of websites:
https://www.veed.io/tools/audio-translator/translate-audio-to-japanese (This one is free)
There are many others you can find by searching 'software to transcribe japanese audio' in google, but I am not sure if you want paid software.